# Show that for all $X \in \mathbb{F}^2$ there is a nonzero two-variable polynomial of degree at most $\sqrt{2 |X|}$ which equals $0$ on all of $X$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

I want to show that for any finite set $X \in \mathbb{F}^2$ (for some field $\mathbb{F}$), there exists a nonzero two-variable polynomial of degree at most $\sqrt{2 |X|}$ which equals $0$ on all of $X$. A two-variable polynomial of degree $n$ (say the variables are $x$ and $y$) is any $\sum_{i=0}^{n}\sum_{j=0}^{n-i}a_{ij}x^iy^j$ where $a_{ij} \in \mathbb{F}$ for all $i, j$.

My only observations so far are that a two-variable polynomial of degree $n$ has at most $1 + 2 + \ldots + (n + 1) = \frac{(n + 2)(n + 1)}{2}$ terms (because the sum $i + j$ in $x^iy^j$ must be at most $n$, with $i, j \geq 0$). This means a two-variable polynomial of degree $\sqrt{2|X|}$ has degree at most $\frac{(\sqrt{2|X|} + 2)(\sqrt{2|X|} + 1)}{2} = \frac{2|X| + 3\sqrt{2|X|} + 2}{2} = |X| + \frac{3}{2}\sqrt{2|X|} + 1$ terms. However, I don't know how to assign $a_{ij}$ to each $x^iy^j$ in order to make the polynomial equal $0$ on $X$.

Could anyone give a hint or a solution to this problem?

Comment: Assign to each point $(x, y) \in X$ the vector of values $x^i y^j, i + j \le n$. Now notice that finding a two-variable polynomial of degree $\le n$ vanishing on these points is equivalent to finding a linear dependence between these vectors. Can you finish from here?

Comment: @QiaochuYuan I'm not sure I follow. Could you explain why finding such a polynomial vanishing on these points is equivalent to finding a linear dependence between these vectors?

Comment: Just write it down carefully. What does it mean for a polynomial to vanish at a point? What does it mean for a polynomial to vanish at all the points in $X$?